# This recursive program in python giving me an error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def fact(number=input("Enter a value:")):
    if number==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return number*fact(number-1)


res=fact()
print(res)
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Open a REPL and run `input("Enter a value:")`. Then input a number and see what the result looks like. It's not a number. What is it?

Answer (score 1):

It is generally bad to initialize parameter variables with functions that don't return constants (like `input`). In addition, `input` returns a string, not an integer so it needs to be converted. I recommend you change it like this:

```
def fact(number):
    if number <= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return number*fact(number-1)

number = int(input("Enter a value:"))
res = fact(number)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting input to integer. By default, it is taking as string.

```py
def fact(number=int(input("Enter a value:"))):
    if number==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return number*fact(number-1)


res=fact()
print(res)
```